# Отправить данные из JS в PHP и записать в Mysql

Tags: javascript, php

Есть JS, он находится на стороне клиента.
JS должен отправить данные на сайт в `index.php`

`index.php` должен эти данные записать в бд.

Я не понимаю, вроде всё правильно делаю но он их не пишет.

JS:

```
function send_data(){
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var one = "123";
   var two = "456"
   request.open("POST", "http://sitename/index.php");
   request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   request.send('one=' + one + 'two=' + two);  
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['one']) && isset($_POST['two'])){
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

$one = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['one']));
$two = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['two']));
$query = "INSERT INTO data VALUES('$one', '$two')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Умм, решилось.
Вот так:

```
function send_data(){
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var one = "123";
   var two = "456"
   var send = 'one=' + encodeURIComponent(one) + '&two=' +encodeURIComponent(two);
   request.open("POST", "http://sitename/index.php");
   request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   request.send(send);  
}
```